# baixar medias do whatsapp API webpackJsonp()

Tags: javascript

eu uso window.Store webpackJsonp, para enviar e receber msg no whatsapp, esse é tipo um evento do javascript para manipular o whatsapp, no entanto não consigo baixar mídia que recebo, aparece o preview, que é a imagem bem pequena, mas queria a original, essa é a __x_mediaData onde fica algo parecido com um blob mas n é um blob:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]